# Styling option group label

Tags: css

Is it possible to style just the label of the optgroup in drop-down selector?

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Group Name">
        <option>My option</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use attribute Selector

```
[label]
{
color: red;
}
```

**EDIT**

```
<select>
<optgroup label="Cars">
<option>Honda</option>
<option>Merc</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Bikes">
<option>Kawasaki</option>
<option>Yamaha</option>
</optgroup>
</select>


optgroup[label="Cars"]
{
color: red;
}

optgroup[label="Bikes"]
{
color: blue;
}

option
{
color: black;
}
```

Comment: This is just an example. Use a more specific selector. As stated by you it will effect the entire group. To solve that use "option {color: black;}

Answer (score 13):

I know that this thread is a bit old, but just in case someone stumbles on it as I have...
It has been mentioned that when styling the optgroup tag that it styles the entire group.  This is true, but if you style the option tag separately, the optgroup formatting will remain as set in the style, but the style formatting for the option which is a child of the optgroup will override the optgroup formatting that is inherited when no style is set for the option.

So, setting the following css style for optgroup will give you red text on a gray background.

```
optgroup {
    background-color: gray;
    color: red;
}
```

If nothing else is done, your entire list will be red text on a gray background.  However, also setting the option style as below will keep the optgroup labels styled red on gray, but the options under the group will be black on white.

```
option {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Using the `[label]` [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** as suggested everywhere **is mostly irrelevant**. You cannot apply styles to HTML attributes. It's merely a modifier to filter out `optgroup` elements. If all your `optgroup` have a `label` then you'll be selecting them all anyway and if some do not have `label` then they'll just opt-out from the style:

```css
optgroup[label]{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<select size="8">
  <optgroup label="Cars">
    <option>Honda</option>
    <option>Merc</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup>
    <option>Not label</option>
    <option>Not label either</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Bikes">
    <option>Kawasaki</option>
    <option>Yamaha</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

The `<select>` tag has the problem of other complex form controls like `<input type="file">`. Original specs assumed that it'd be up to the browser how to display it (in fact, it was typically a builtin GUI control provided by the underlying library) and don't provide comprehensive means to style it. Just look at this screen-shot found in the [W3C HTML 4.01 Specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/interact/forms.html#h-17.6):

[image: optgroup at HTML4]

Back to our problem, there're two facts to take into account:

- The `<optgroup>` is a block that includes child `<option>`s
- The label does not really have a node of its own

This snippet makes it more clear:

```css
optgroup{
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
optgroup option{
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid orange;
}
```

```html
<select size="13">
  <optgroup label="Cars">
    <option>Honda</option>
    <option>Merc</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Bikes">
    <option>Kawasaki</option>
    <option>Yamaha</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

So all you can do is to apply styles to `<optgroup>` (understanding you can't tell the label apart from the rest of items) and then overwrite them as necessary for child options.

Comment: Some of the CSS properties such as `border` are only rendered when the `<select>` has a `size` attribute greater than 1. I expect this is the case because with size > 1, the select's contents are permanently rendered to the page, but when size = 1 (or isn't specified - the normal case for a select), the contents are only rendered when the select is clicked. In that case both `<option>` and `<optgroup>` ignore a bunch of CSS properties including border and margin. (Tested on Chrome Windows. This will be totally different again on mobile).

Answer (score 4):

```
<style type="text/css">
    optgroup[label] {
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
```

or

```
<style type="text/css">
    optgroup[label="Group Name"] {
        background: #FFFFFF;
    }
</style>
```

if you want it to be label specific.

Comment: Reset the <option> as "option {color: black;}. This will override the styles set on optgroup