# styles on optgroup

Tags: css, optgroup

How can you put a style on a optgroup in a select tag?

http://jsfiddle.net/UCNJ8/3/

js:

```
$('<select></select>').appendTo('body').append('<option value="0">test</option>')
    .append($('<optgroup label="group"></optgroup>')
            .append('<option value="1">group test</option>'));
```

css:

```
select.optgroup[label] {
    font-style:normal;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling option group label](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415747/styling-option-group-label)

Comment: select.optgroup[label] {
 font-style:normal;
} this still doesn't work

Comment: @You are not using the dot properly - those are for classes. You don't have a class named `optgroup`. Just use `optgroup[label]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the CSS selector `select optgroup` instead.

Be aware that not every browser will respect `optgroup` rules (Webkit, for example). With that in mind, you might like to try a jQuery plugin that allows complete, cross-browsing styling of form elements; such as [Uniform](http://uniformjs.com/).

Comment: it works.. but how can I then reduce or remove the left padding/margin of the optgroup in the select?

Comment: Well, as I say, it won't style all browsers, but if you want to *try* remove the padding & margin, then use the appropriate style declarations; `select optgroup { margin: 0; padding: 0; }`