# Angular material: changing background color of optiongroup doesn't work

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm using the [`<mat-select>`](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview) component from Angular Material to let a user pick a dormitory out of a list of dormitories. The list is grouped by different cities, but the user can only click on the dormitories, not the cities.
Everything is working so far, but for cooler styling I want to change the background color of the list. So far I can change the background color of the options (the dormitories) easily with

```html
<mat-option style="background-color: rgb(0, 168, 255, 0.5);>
```

But when I try to change the background color of the option groups (which hold the cities), it doesn't work:

```html
<mat-optgroup style="background-color: rgb(0, 168, 255, 0.8);">
```

So my result looks like this:

[image]

This is the full code I'm using to create the component:

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>wohnheim</mat-label>
    <mat-select [formcontrol]="dormcontrol" (selectionchange)="changeselecteddorm($event)">
        <mat-optgroup style="background-color: rgb(0, 168, 255, 0.5);" *ngfor="let group of dormgroups"  [label]="group.name" [disabled]="group.disabled">
            <mat-option style="background-color: rgb(0, 168, 255, 0.5);" *ngfor="let dorms of group.dorms" [value]="dorms.name">
                {{dorms.name}}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-optgroup>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

Where an option-group is always a city/dormGroup (like "Göppingen" or "Ludwigsburg") and the options are dorms in that city, like "Studentendorf Göppingen" or "OFD Wohnturm". What I want is the cities to also have a blue background.

I also tried adding this to my CSS as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415747/styling-option-group-label), but it didn't change anything:

```css
optgroup {
    background-color: gray;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix it by adding `display: block` rule to that `mat-optgroup` tag:

```html
<mat-optgroup style="background-color: rgb(0, 168, 255, 0.5); display: block">
                                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or you can add the same in your component css file:

```css
mat-optgroup {
    display: block;
    background-color: rgb(0, 168, 255, 0.5);
}
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fjqza4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fselect.css)**

Answer (score 1):

Set class style in style.css

This time you have to 'force' styles with !important too.

style.css

```
.mat-optgroup{ 
width:2000px !important; 
background-color: red !important; 
font-size: 10px !important; }
```